# Thumbnail and attachment syntax on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, syntax

I use code like this, but unfortunately did not work. The error is the image failed to load, but the code display on the page.

```
 <?php 
$nextthumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID);
$img_urltest = wp_get_attachment_url( $nextthumb,'full' ); 
$imagetest = aq_resize( $img_urltest, 500,325, true );  

$thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
$img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); 
$image = aq_resize( $img_url, 500,325, true ); 
 ?>
 <img src=" 
 <?php if($image) { 
 echo $image; 
 } 
 else { 
 echo $nextthumb; 
 } 
 ?>
 "alt="<?php  echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>"/>
```

Comment: the image failed to load, but the code display on the page.

Comment: Can you do a view source and paste the HTML that's being generated for this piece of code?